# Including Duplicate Tables using Django's ORM Extra()

Tags: python, sql, django, sparql, django-orm

I'm trying to implement a simple triplestore using Django's ORM. I'd like to be able to search for arbitrarily complex triple patterns (e.g. as you would with SparQL).

To do this, I'm attempting to use the [.extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method. However, even though the docs mention it can, in theory, handle duplicate references to the same table by automatically creating an alias for the duplicate table references, I've found it does not do this in practice.

For example, say I have the following model in my "triple" app:

```
class Triple(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    predicate = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    object = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and I have the following triples stored in my database:

```
subject predicate object
bob has-a hat .
bob knows sue .
sue has-a house .
bob knows tom .
```

Now, say I want to query the names of everyone bob knows who has a house. In SQL, I'd simply do:

```
SELECT t2.subject AS name
FROM triple_triple t1
INNER JOIN triple_triple t2 ON
    t1.subject = 'bob'
AND t1.predicate = 'knows'
AND t1.object = t2.subject
AND t2.predicate = 'has-a'
AND t2.object = 'house'
```

I'm not completely sure what this would look like with Django's ORM, although I think it would be along the lines of:

```
q = Triple.objects.filter(subject='bob', predicate='knows')
q = q.extra(tables=['triple_triple'], where=["triple_triple.object=t1.subject AND t1.predicate = 'has-a' AND t1.object = 'house'"])
q.values('t1.subject')
```

Unfortunately, this fails with the error "DatabaseError: no such column: t1.subject"

Running print q.query shows:

```
SELECT "triple_triple"."subject" FROM "triple_triple" WHERE ("triple_triple"."subject" = 'bob' AND "triple_triple"."predicate" = 'knows'
AND triple_triple.object = t1.subject AND t1.predicate = 'has-a' AND t1.object = 'house')
```

which appears to show that the tables param in my call to .extra() is being ignored, as there's no second reference to triple_triple inserted anywhere.

Why is this happening? What's the appropriate way to refer to complex relationships between records in the same table using Django's ORM?

EDIT: I found this [useful snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/236/) for including custom SQL via .extra() so that it's usable inside a model manager.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you're missing is the select parameter (for the extra method)

This seems to work:

```
qs = Triple.objects.filter(subject="bob", predicate="knows").extra(
          select={'known': "t1.subject"},
          tables=['"triple_triple" AS "t1"'],
          where=['''triple_triple.object=t1.subject 
                    AND t1.predicate="has-a" AND t1.object="'''])

qs.values("known")
```

Comment: Thanks. Strange that it would drop the additional table simply because it wasn't referenced in the SELECT, since this breaks the query when the second table is used to filter in the WHERE clause. Possible bug?

Comment: @ Cerin: I don't think it is a bug, my dirty interpretation of this is that you use the where param to have more conditions and the select to add more columns to the returned queryset.

Comment: @ Tommaso: My point is it seems I can't use multiple tables unless I SELECT at least one column from each table. This doesn't make sense, because I won't always want or need to SELECT columns from each table I want to JOIN. That's why I think this is either a bug or a poorly designed feature.

Comment: Does the code above actually work for you? My Django escapes the table s given to extra(), so tables=['"triple_triple" AS "t1"'] does't work in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue where Django escapes (adds back-ticks) to my table names, meaning that I can't add an alias manually; the resulting FROM clause looks like this:

`"mytable" AS T100`

But at the same time, Django won't automatically create aliases for you if the table is already mentioned; instead it ignores the tables and just adds on the WHERE clauses as if they refer to the original tables.

The documentation for Django 1.8 suggests that .extra() will create aliases for you:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

But this doesn't appear to be the case for my query, possibly because original table is part of a LEFT OUTER JOIN rather than a simple FROM x,y,z clause.